# Google map blank when used with master page

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps

I wrote a google map lookup page. Everthing worked fine until I referenced the page to use a master page. I removed the form tag from the master page as the search button on the map page is a submit button. Everything else on my page appears but the google map div appears with map navigation controls and logo but no map visuals appear.

I retested with the previous, non master page version and the map appears correctly. Any thoughts on what I'm missing?

Comment: Could you provide a code sample?

Comment: Would love to but it won't fit. I'm using Donn Felkers store locator at http://blog.donnfelker.com/post/HOWTO-Build-a-Store-Locator-in-ASPNET.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please view below Code and let me know its useful ...

**MasterPage Code ( GMap.master page)**

```
< body onload="initialize()"  onunload="GUnload()"  >  
< form id="form1" runat="server" >
    < div >
        < asp:contentplaceholder id="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server" >
        < /asp:contentplaceholder >
    < /div >
    < /form >
< /body >
```

**GMatTest.aspx Page which is used GMap.Master page**

```
< %@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/GMap.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeFile="GMapTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="GMapTest" Title="Google Map Page" % >


< asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="Server" >


    < script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=< % = AppConfig.GoogleMapApiKey % >"
        type="text/javascript" >< /script >

    < script type="text/javascript" >

    var map = null;
    var geocoder = null;
    var latsgn = 1;
    var lgsgn = 1;
    var zm = 0; 
    var marker = null;    

    function initialize()
     {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) 
      {
       var latitude=  "";
       var longitude= "";

       map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));


         var center = new GLatLng(0,0);
         map.setCenter(center, 17);

         map.addControl(new GLargeMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GScaleControl());
        map.enableScrollWheelZoom();

        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());

        map.enableDoubleClickZoom();

         marker = new GMarker(center,{draggable: true});

         geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();


       GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
        var point = marker.getLatLng();
         marker.openInfoWindowHtml("Latitude: " + point.y + "< /br > Longitude: " + point.x  );
      });

       GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        var point = marker.getLatLng();        

      });


        map.addOverlay(marker);
        GEvent.trigger(marker, "click");

        if (latitude  > 0 &&  longitude  > 0)
        {
        }
        else
        {       

            showAddress();

        }
      }
     }
```

Below porsion is continue so please copy it also

```
function showAddress() 
{
     var isAddressFound=false;  
     var companyAddress = '';  
     var address='satyam mall, vastrapur, ahmedabad, gujrat, india';  
     if (geocoder)   
    {  
         geocoder.getLatLng(address,function(point) {   
                             if (!point) {  
                            alert(address + " not found");  

                             } else {  
                                isAddressFound =true;  
                             map.setCenter(point,17);  
                             zm = 1;  
                             marker.setPoint(point);  
                             GEvent.trigger(marker, "click");  
                             }  
                         }  
         );  



//If address not found then redirect to company address

     if(!isAddressFound)
     {     
         geocoder.getLatLng(companyAddress,
         function(point) { 
         if (!point) { 
         } else {
            isAddressFound =true;
         map.setCenter(point,17);
         zm = 1;
         marker.setPoint(point);
         GEvent.trigger(marker, "click");
         }
         }
         );
     }
 }
}
< /script >

< div id="map_canvas" style="width: 100%; height: 425px" >
< /div >
< /asp:Content >
```

Comment: Note above code uses deprecated V2 version of Google Maps API.

Answer (score 1):

this is the code i used.it works fine here but whenever i add master page it does not perform any use functionality

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>Find latitude and longitude with Google Maps</title>
      <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps?file=api&amp;v=2&amp;key=ABQIAAAAPkZq56tNYNmeuZjNQQ2p3hT0NZP-HbfQNNfWb9Z5SLbjZKYKwBTrGBqtttFmF2d-kWv2B2nqW_NyEQ"
      type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

 function load() {
      if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
        var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
        map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
        map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
        var center = new GLatLng(48.89364,      2.33739);
        map.setCenter(center, 15);
        geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
        var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});  
        map.addOverlay(marker);
        document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = center.lat().toFixed(6);
        document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = center.lng().toFixed(6);

      GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
       var point = marker.getPoint();
          map.panTo(point);
       document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = point.lat().toFixed(6);
       document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = point.lng().toFixed(6);

        });


     GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function() {
          map.clearOverlays();
    var center = map.getCenter();
          var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});
          map.addOverlay(marker);
          document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = center.lat().toFixed(6);
       document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = center.lng().toFixed(6);


     GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
      var point =marker.getPoint();
         map.panTo(point);
      document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = point.lat().toFixed(6);
         document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = point.lng().toFixed(6);

        });

        });

      }
    }

       function showAddress(address) {
       var map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"));
       map.addControl(new GSmallMapControl());
       map.addControl(new GMapTypeControl());
       if (geocoder) {
        geocoder.getLatLng(
          address,
          function(point) {
            if (!point) {
              alert(address + " not found");
            } else {
          document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = point.lat().toFixed(6);
       document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = point.lng().toFixed(6);
         map.clearOverlays()
            map.setCenter(point, 14);
   var marker = new GMarker(point, {draggable: true});  
         map.addOverlay(marker);

        GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
      var pt = marker.getPoint();
         map.panTo(pt);
      document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = pt.lat().toFixed(6);
         document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = pt.lng().toFixed(6);
        });


     GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", function() {
          map.clearOverlays();
    var center = map.getCenter();
          var marker = new GMarker(center, {draggable: true});
          map.addOverlay(marker);
          document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = center.lat().toFixed(6);
       document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = center.lng().toFixed(6);

     GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function() {
     var pt = marker.getPoint();
        map.panTo(pt);
    document.getElementById("lat").innerHTML = pt.lat().toFixed(6);
       document.getElementById("lng").innerHTML = pt.lng().toFixed(6);
        });

        });

            }
          }
        );
      }
    }
    </script>
  </head>


<body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()" >

<p>This page uses the Google Maps API to find out accurate geographical coordinates (latitude and longitude) for any place on Earth. <br/>It provides two ways to search, either by moving around the map and zooming in, or by typing an address if the place is unknown.<br/>
<i>
    <p> The default location and address are those of Mondeca office in Paris.<br />
   <p><b> Find coordinates by moving around the map</b></p> <p>1. Drag and drop the map to broad location. <br/>
    2. Zoom in for greater accuracy. <br/>
    3. Drag and drop the marker to pinpoint the place. The coordinates are refreshed at the end of each move.  </p>

  <form action="#" onsubmit="showAddress(this.address.value); return false">
     <p>        
      <input type="text" size="60" name="address" value="3 cit&eacute; Nollez Paris France" />
      <input type="submit" value="Search!" />
      </p>
    </form>

 <p align="left">

 <table  bgcolor="#FFFFCC" width="300">
  <tr>
    <td width="100"><b>Latitude</b></td>
    <td id="lat"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td width="100"><b>Longitude</b></td>
    <td id="lng"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
 </p>
  <p>
  <div align="center" id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"><br/></div>
   </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It was same problem as mentioned above. when I used master page no google map was drawn. I found solution later.

You need to call the Javascript function in .aspx page where you want to show google map (like `initialize();`) may be different in your case.

code in my case:

```
<script type="text/javascript"">
    window.onload = function () {
        DrawGoogleMap();
    }

    function DrawGoogleMap() {
        if (GBrowserIsCompatible()) {
            map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("GoogleMap_Div"));
            geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();

            GService.GetGoogleObject(fGetGoogleObject);
        }
    } 

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

One thing that can change when you add a master page is your elements ids.

If the div you are displaying the map in has `runat="server"` on it, you could have a problem.
You would add that tag so you could manipulate the div from code-behind.

So, if my div looks like this:

```
<div id="gmap" runat="server"></div>
```

If so, when you are initializing your map, you need to get the ClientId of the div.  That would look like this:

```
var mapDiv = '<%= gmap.ClientID %>';
var map = new GMap2(mapDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

Load up FireFox and FireBug, start looking for javascript errors.
One item that I have found, you have to call setCenter on the map for it to display.
Also, if you are adding markers (or layers), you have to add the marker after you call setCenter.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having to force the div to visible

See this thread on google maps support forums:

http://groups.google.com/group/Google-Maps-Troubleshooting/browse_thread/thread/0d27b66eef5f5d9e/1259a2991412f796?lnk=raot

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

the code i used is

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"  CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <META NAME="AUTHOR" CONTENT="Rakshith Krishnappa">
    <META NAME="DESCRIPTION" CONTENT="KML Tool - Get Latitude and Longitude for KML Polyline">
    <META NAME="KEYWORDS" CONTENT="Google, maps, mashup, tools, kml, polyline">
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="ALL"> 
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
    <title>Mapmash | Geocoder Tool | Geocode - Reverse Geocode - IP Geocode</title>
    <%--<style type="text/css">
    <!--
      html {
        height: 100%; width:100%;overflow:hidden;
      } 
      body {
      background-color: white;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size:10pt
     }
     h1 {
     font-size: 18pt;
     }   
      #map {
      height: 100%;
           } 
    #hand_b {
      width:31px;
      height:31px;
      background-image: url(http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/t/Bsu.png);
    }
    #hand_b.selected {
      background-image: url(http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/t/Bsd.png);
    }

    #placemark_b {
      width:31px;
      height:31px;
      background-image: url(http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/t/Bmu.png);
    }
    #placemark_b.selected {
      background-image: url(http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/t/Bmd.png);
    }

    #line_b {
      width:31px;
      height:31px;
      background-image: url(http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/t/Blu.png);
    }
    #line_b.selected {
      background-image: url(http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/t/Bld.png);
    }

    #shape_b {
      width:31px;
      height:31px;
      background-image: url(http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/t/Bpu.png);
    }
    #shape_b.selected {
      background-image: url(http://google.com/mapfiles/ms/t/Bpd.png);
    }          
    --> 
    </style>
    <style type="text/css">
    v\:* {
      behavior:url(#default#VML);
    }
    </style>--%>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAAPkZq56tNYNmeuZjNQQ2p3hT0NZP-HbfQNNfWb9Z5SLbjZKYKwBTrGBqtttFmF2d-kWv2B2nqW_NyEQ"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("maps", "2");
    </script>
    <script src="dragzoom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://adserver.lat49.com/lat49/v0.10/lat49.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Start of Google Analytics Code -->
    <script src="http://www.google-analytics.com/urchin.js" type="text/javascript">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    _uacct = "UA-2417064-1";
    urchinTracker();
    </script>
    <!-- End of Google Analytics Code -->   
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    //rakf1 modified code taken from these 2 sources: - http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocationv4.php and - Distance Measurement Tool - Google Mapplets
    // argItems code taken from 
    // http://www.evolt.org/article/Javascript_to_Parse_URLs_in_the_Browser/17/14435/?format=print

    var map;
    var coordinates = '';
    var geocoder = new GClientGeocoder();
    var added = 0;
    var marker;

    function write_point() {
        var position = marker.getPoint();
        var lat = position.y.toFixed(6);
        var lng = position.x.toFixed(6);

        coordinates = lng + "," + lat + "\n";
        document.getElementById("attribute").value = 'lat="'+lat+'" lng="'+lng+'"';
        document.getElementById("latlng").value = '<lat>'+lat+'</lat>\n<lng>'+lng+'</lng>';
        document.getElementById("kml").value = lng+','+lat;
        document.getElementById("coord").value = marker.getPoint().toUrlValue();            
    }

    function get_address1() {
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
            var position = marker.getPoint();
            var lat = position.y.toFixed(6);
            var lng = position.x.toFixed(6);
            var html = 'FreeReverseGeo.com (~address):<br><iframe id="RSIFrame" name="RSIFrame" style="overflow:hidden; width:200px; height:55px; border: 1px" src="http://www.freereversegeo.com/gmap-api.php?lat_1=' + lat + '&lng_1=' + lng + '"></iframe><br>('+lat+','+lng+')';
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);                    
        });     
    }

    function get_address() {
        GEvent.addListener(marker, "click", function(){
            var position = marker.getPoint();
            geocoder.getLocations(position, function(addresses) {
              if(addresses.Status.code != 200) {
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<b>Google Reverse Geocode:</b><br>Reverse geocoder failed to find an address for " + position.toUrlValue());
              }
              else {
                address = addresses.Placemark[0];
                var html = address.address;
                marker.openInfoWindowHtml("<b>Google Reverse Geocode:</b><br>"+html);
              }
            });                 
        });     
    }


    function my_location() {
        if (google.loader.ClientLocation) {
            var cl = google.loader.ClientLocation;
            var html = 'Google ClientLocation: <br><font size="+1">' + cl.address.city + ', ' + cl.address.region+ '<br> ' + cl.address.country+'</font><br>('+cl.latitude+','+cl.longitude+')'; 
            var point = new GLatLng(cl.latitude, cl.longitude);
            if(!marker) {
            map.setZoom(12);
            marker = new GMarker(point,{title: "Click to get address", draggable: true});
            map.addOverlay(marker); 
            added = 1;
            }
            map.setCenter(point);
            marker.setPoint(point);
            marker.openInfoWindowHtml(html);
        }
    }

    function draw_point() { 
        GEvent.addListener(map, 'click', function(overlay, point) {
            if (point && !added) {
                marker = new GMarker(point, {icon:G_DEFAULT_ICON, draggable: true, title: "Click to get address"});             
                map.addOverlay(marker);
                added = 1;
                GEvent.addListener(marker, "dragend", function(){
                    write_point();
                }); 
            }
            else if (point && added) {
                marker.setPoint(point); 
            }
            write_point();
            get_address();
        });

    }



    function showAddress(address) {
      geocoder.getLatLng(
        address,
        function(point) {
          if (!point) {
            alert(address + " not found");
          } else {
            map.setCenter(point, 11);
            if(!marker) {
                marker = new GMarker(point, {icon:G_DEFAULT_ICON, draggable: true, title: "Click to get address"});             
                map.addOverlay(marker); 
                get_address();
                added = 1;
            }
            marker.setPoint(point); 
            write_point();
            }
        }
      );
    }

    function showLat49Ads(){
        Lat49.initAds(19);
        var center = map.getCenter();
        var lat = center.lat();
        var lng = center.lng();
        var zoomlevel = Lat49.Tile.convertGMap2Zoom(map.getZoom());
        Lat49.updateAdByLatLon("lat49ads", lat, lng, zoomlevel);
    }

    function load(){

        map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map"),{draggableCursor: 'crosshair', draggingCursor: 'crosshair'});
        map.addControl(new GSmallZoomControl());
        map.addControl(new GMenuMapTypeControl(),new GControlPosition(G_ANCHOR_TOP_LEFT, new GSize(61,7)));
        map.addMapType(G_PHYSICAL_MAP);
        map.addControl(new GOverviewMapControl());
        var boxStyleOpts = { opacity: .2, border: "2px solid yellow" };         
        var otherOpts = {
          buttonHTML: "<img src='zoom-control-inactive1.png' title='Drag Zoom' />",
          buttonZoomingHTML: "<img src='zoom-control-active1.png' title='Drag Zoom: Cancel' />",
          buttonStartingStyle: {width: '15px', height: '15px'},
          overlayRemoveTime: 0 };
        map.addControl(new DragZoomControl(boxStyleOpts, otherOpts, {}), new GControlPosition(G_ANCHOR_TOP_LEFT, new GSize(25,7)));
        map.setCenter(new GLatLng(37.35, -121.93), 12);

        draw_point();
        showLat49Ads();
        GEvent.addListener(map, "moveend", showLat49Ads);
     }
    //]]>
    </script>       
  </head>
  <body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
    <table width="100%" height="100%" style="width:100%; height:100%">
        <tr style="vertical-align:top">
            <td style="width:320px">
                <table><tr>             
                </tr></table>
            </td>
            <td>
            </td>
            <td align="right">
                <nobr>
                  <form action="#" onsubmit="showAddress(this.address.value); return false">
                    <input type="text" size="30" name="address" value="Chicago, IL" />
                    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
                  </form>
                </nobr>    
            </td>
        </tr>  
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <div style="width:300px;font-size:8pt"><h1>GeoCoder</h1>Click on the map or search a place to add a marker and drag marker around to get marker position coordinates. Click on marker to get approximate address.</div>
                <br><span style="font-size:8pt"><b>Coordinates (lat, lng):</b> [for GLatLng]</span><br>
                <input type="text" size="30" id="coord" onclick="this.select()"/>
                <br><br><span style="font-size:8pt"><b>Coordinates (lng, lat):</b> [for KML]</span><br>
                <input type="text" size="30" id="kml" onclick="this.select()"/>
                <br><br><span style="font-size:8pt"><b>Coordinates (lat="x.xx" lng="x.xx"):</b></span><br>
                <input type="text" size="30" id="attribute" onclick="this.select()"/>
                <br><br><span style="font-size:8pt"><b>Coordinates (&lt;lat&gt; &lt;lng&gt;):</b></span><br>
                <textarea rows="2" cols="24" id="latlng" onclick="this.select()" ></textarea>               
                <br>
                <br>    
                    <script type="text/javascript"><!--
                    google_ad_client = "pub-2773616400896769";
                    /* maptools_300x250_01 */
                    google_ad_slot = "1034665593";
                    google_ad_width = 300;
                    google_ad_height = 250;
                    //-->
                    </script>
                    <script type="text/javascript"
                    src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js">
                    </script>   
            </td>       
            <td colspan="2" width="100%" height="100%">
                <div style="position:relative;width:100%;height:100%">
                    <div id="lat49ads" lat49adposition="top-right" 
                        style="position:absolute;top:7px; right:4px; width:125px; height:133;z-index:99999;"></div>             
                    <div id="map" style="width:100%;height:400px;min-height:400px;border:1px solid #999;"></div>
                </div> 
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

if anyone have any idea regarding to code i posted earlier please post a comment.

thanks